# Find the shaded area, given the sides:

Tags: geometry, triangles

The given sides were $AC=BD=25$, $AD=BC=15$, and $DC=7$. No other explanations were given to this problem.

[image]

I tried to connect $A$ and $B$ to form an isosceles trapezoid then tried to work around with similar triangles but found no luck solving it.

Comment: You can't have a triangle with sides $25,15,7$.

Comment: Ah, right. No wonder why this problem was weird. Maybe my teacher sent the wrong numbers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Notice, in $\Delta ACD$, $AD+DC=15+7=22<25$ (third side $AC$).

A triangle will exist iff the sum of any two sides is greater than third side. Therefore, $\Delta ACD$ and $\Delta BCD$ do not exist.